# Excel Conditional format from unknown ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I am a programmer and therefore, a complete novice at using Excel. I have a spreadsheet with a lot of data about change controls. Among the columns are `CC Ref`, `Change Agent` and `Closing Change Agent`. Multiple change agents can be assigned to one change control request, so there are multiple rows for each change control (one for each change agent added). Also, there is a column that contains the change agent who closed the change control:
[image: Pending conditional formatting]

Above displays the change agents for 3 change controls. What I want to do is apply conditional formatting to column J if the closing change agent is not among those added to the change control. e.g:
[image: Conditionally formatted]

My best guess is that I'd need to do a `VLOOKUP` of column C where column B = column B of current row, and apply the conditional formatting if nothing is returned. Cannot get that to work, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    =NOT(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$9,$B2,$C$2:$C$9,$J2))
```

Should work. You need to test two criteria so that's why you use COUNTIFS instead of COUNTIF.